# Get Complete Servers List

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So how to get all the servers list my bot has connected or installed. I used below code but its now working no idea why.

```
servers = list(bot.servers)
print("Connected on " + str(len(bot.servers)) + "servers:")
for x in range(len(servers)):
    print('  ' + servers[x-1].name)
```

My bot.py full code

```
token = "This is my Token" # This is what the bot uses to log into Discord.
prefix = "?" # This will be used at the start of commands.

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)
bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print(discord.__version__)
    print('------')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    msg = 'Pong {0.author.mention}'.format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def hello(ctx):
    msg = 'hello... {0.author.mention}'.format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you said how it isn't working.  Do you get the wrong output?  No output at all?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: Also, `for server in servers: print('  ' + server)` is much more pythonic.

Comment: Seems like servers isn't an attribute of the commands.Bot class: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#bot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `async` branch, [`bot.servers`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/async/api.html#discord.Client.servers) returns an iterable of all the servers the bot can see.

For the `rewrite` branch, `server` has been renamed to `guild`, so use [`bot.guilds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.guilds) instead.

You can modify your `on_ready` event to print out all the server names.

**async**

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print(discord.__version__)
    print('------')

    print('Servers connected to:')
    for server in bot.servers:
        print(server.name)
```

**rewrite**

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print(discord.__version__)
    print('------')

    print('Servers connected to:')
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        print(guild.name)
```

Comment: Thank you bro its working is it possible to get server ID along with Server name ?

Comment: nvm got it changed `print(server.name)` to `print(server.id)` it worked

Comment: Glad it's working! For future reference, here are the attributes of the `server` class that you can access: http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#server

Comment: Its too old bruh

Comment: @BlackThunder Updated to include `rewrite` branch code and doc

Answer (score 2):

I've had a little bit of fun with the code. Here is a currently working version.

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
print(f'Currently at {len(bot.guilds)} servers!')
print('Servers connected to:')
print('')
for server in bot.guilds:
    print(server.name)
```

This should work just fine for you.